# Correct way to launch and close interactive ipython session from notepad++

Tags: python, cmd, notepad++, ipython

What I would like to do is launch an interactive ipython session from notepad++, and keep the window open (in interactive mode) after a script completes, but for the window to close once I exit from ipython. This seems like a fairly simple task, but I'm having trouble finding the answer.

In notepad++, I have entered the following for the `Run` command (`F5`):

```
cmd /k ipython -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

This works fine: it opens and runs the script I am editing using ipython, and keeps the ipython session open once the script is complete.

However, after entering the `exit` command, I have to enter `exit` a second time at the command prompt) to close the window (or close it with the mouse). It would be nice if I didn't have to enter `exit` twice. Is there a solution to get things working the way I want them to work?

I have tried removing `/k` flag (my understanding is this flag keeps the window open):

```
cmd ipython -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

However, the script does not seem to run at all in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Well I discovered the answer just before I was about to post the question! Instead of deleting it altogether, I thought I would go ahead and post the resolution so that others can find it later. It turned out to be pretty simple!:

```
ipython -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

(Note that in order for this to work, ipython must be available as a program to be run from a command prompt.)